# Uniform bounds for a coupled parabolic system of PDE (linear)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Let $V=H^1(\Omega)$ and $H=L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. Define $W = \{ w \in L^2(0,T;V) : w_t \in L^2(0,T;V^*)\}$.

Consider the system, with $u^\epsilon, v^\epsilon \in W,$
$$u^\epsilon_t + Au^\epsilon + Bu^\epsilon +\epsilon v^\epsilon = f$$
$$v^\epsilon_t - Av^\epsilon + \epsilon u^\epsilon = g$$
$$u^\epsilon(0) = u^\epsilon(T) - l(u^\epsilon(T))$$
$$v^\epsilon(T) =  v^\epsilon(0) - l(v^\epsilon(0))$$
$$\text{Condition (1)}$$
where $A:L^2(0,T;V) \to L^2(0,T;V^*)$ is a bounded self-adjoint linear map such that $\langle Aw,w\rangle \geq C_1\int_0^T|w|^2_{V} - C_2\int_0^T|w|^2_H$, $B:L^2(0,T;V) \to L^2(0,T;V^*)$ is a bounded linear map, where $l \in H^*$ and $f$ and $g$ are given in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ and the equation is considered in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ and Condition (1) an extra condition involving $l(u^\epsilon(0))$ and $l(v^\epsilon(T))$ which happens to imply that
$$\int_0^T\frac{d}{dt}\int_\Omega u(t)v(t) = 0.$$

**Question** : Is it possible to obtain any estimates on $u^\epsilon$ and $v^\epsilon$ in any norms (eg. $|u^\epsilon|_{L^2(0,T;V)}$ or $|u^\epsilon_t|_{L^2(0,T;V^*)}$) that are independent of $\epsilon$?

- The aim is to send $\epsilon \to 0$ and extract weak-convergent subsequences so that I can deduce something about the system 
  $$u_t + Au + Bu= f$$
  $$v_t - Av = g.$$
  Specifically I only care about the equation for $u$.
- Does anyone know any techniques? I tried testing the equations with $u^\epsilon, v^\epsilon$ and so on but couldn't achieve it. Gronwall gives me a $|u^\epsilon(0)|$ and $|v^\epsilon(0)|$ on the right hand side which is not wanted.
- Maybe I should consider a different regularisation with $\epsilon$ since I am unable to find any uniform bounds.